# Was bedeutet »Asten« in »Landes-Asten-Konferenz«?

Tags: meaning

Ich bin heute über diesen Begriff in mehreren verschiedenen Schreibweisen gestoßen:

> Landesastenkonferenz
>   Landes-Asten-Konferenz
>   Landes-ASten-Konferenz

Die Suche nach diesen Begriff bei Wikipedia leitet mich zu [Landesstudierendenvertretung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landesstudierendenvertretung) weiter, wodurch ich zwar weis, was das gesamte Kompositum bedeutet, aber der mittlere Teil »*Asten*« wird weder auf dieser Seite, noch auf einer der von mir konsultierten verlinkten Seiten, erläutert.

Daher nun meine Frage:

> Was bedeutet »Asten« in »Landes-Asten-Konferenz«?

Comment: Hah, gute Frage, denn das ist wahrscheinlich schwer nachzuschlagen, wenn man den Singular nicht kennt. Ohne Kontext habe ich es auch nicht verstanden

Comment: Obwohl mir der Begriff AStA und auch der Plural vertraut ist, habe ich ihn erst in der 3. Schreibweise verstanden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ein [AStA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allgemeiner_Studierendenausschuss) an einer deutschen Hochschule ist der

> **A**llgemeine **St**udierenden**a**usschuss

"Die ASten" ist einfach der Plural davon.

(zu meiner Zeit hieß das noch "Allgemeiner Studentenausschuss" und man hat nicht so viel Kapazität daran gegeben, sich "genderneutrale Ausdrücke" auszudenken)

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/AStA) meint, sowohl "Asten" als auch "Asta" und "Astas" wäre ein geeigneter Plural.

Gemeint ist mit dieser zum Wort erhobenen ursprünglichen Abkürzung die gewählte Repräsentation der Studenten gegenüber z.B. der Hochschulleitung. Das entspricht ganz grob der UV (Universitätsvertretung der  Studierenden) an einer Hochschule in Österreich.

Comment: *Genderneutrale und genderinnenneutrale* bitte!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann *AusdruckInnen*

Comment: Völlig falsch. Wenn überhaupt schon *Neutrale* und *Neutralinnen.*

Comment: Ad Gender und so: Vor ca. einem Jahr wurden im Fernsehen Kinder nach ihrem Berufswunsch gefragt. Ein Mädchen antwortete: »*Krankenschwester**in***«.

Comment: Sehr geehrte Frauen und Frauinnen...